# como puedo declarar una ecuacion en un for para que todos los valores de mi arreglo lo hagan

Tags: python, array, bucle-for

quisiera saber como puedo hacer que una función, tome todos los valores de mi arreglo. y que los guarde en una nueva variable.

adjunto mi código, espero que sirva

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = [36.83, 31.75, 43.815, 36.83, 32.06, 45.08, 35.88]
p = [0.77, 0.48, 1.16, 0.73, 0.48, 1.39, 0.65]
c = [24.77, 21.29, 27.94, 24.77, 21.59, 31.75, 22.86]

for i in (l,p, c):
    k = (l * c**2)/29
    print(k)
```

Comment: Hola vngm, no se termina de entender muy bién que quieres obtener, sospecho que quieres iterar sobre las tres listas de forma paralela, es decir aplicar la función usando los items en la primera posición de las listas, después aplicarla sobre los items situados en segunda posición, etc, para al final obtener una lista con los resultados ¿Es esto o no?

Comment: Si, es justo eso

Answer (score 0):

Si haces `for i in (l, p, c)` el `for` itera sobre la tupla de listas `(l, p, c)` por lo que itera 3 veces y en cada una de ella `i` hará referencia a una de las listas.

Para iterar sobre los items de varios iterables de la misma longitud paralelamente usa el built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Luego en cada iteración solo tienes que ir añadiendo el resultado a una lista vacía creada antes de iniciar el `for` usando el método `list.append()`

```
l = [36.83, 31.75, 43.815, 36.83, 32.06, 45.08, 35.88]
p = [0.77, 0.48, 1.16, 0.73, 0.48, 1.39, 0.65]
c = [24.77, 21.29, 27.94, 24.77, 21.59, 31.75, 22.86]

r = []
for vl, vc in zip(l, c):
    k = (vl * vc**2) / 29
    r.append(k)
```

Para más eficiencia usa listas por compresión:

```
l = [36.83, 31.75, 43.815, 36.83, 32.06, 45.08, 35.88]
p = [0.77, 0.48, 1.16, 0.73, 0.48, 1.39, 0.65]
c = [24.77, 21.29, 27.94, 24.77, 21.59, 31.75, 22.86]

r = [(vl * vc**2) / 29 for vl, vc in zip(l, c)]
```

Puedes usar una función externa si es necesario que calcule cada item:

```
l = [36.83, 31.75, 43.815, 36.83, 32.06, 45.08, 35.88]
p = [0.77, 0.48, 1.16, 0.73, 0.48, 1.39, 0.65]
c = [24.77, 21.29, 27.94, 24.77, 21.59, 31.75, 22.86]

def foo(l, c):
    return (vl * vc**2) / 29

r = [foo(vl, vc) for vl, vc  in zip(l, c)]
#r = [foo(*values) for values in zip(l, c)]
```

En cualquier caso el resultado es:

> ```
> >>> r
> [779.212183,
>  496.24604051724134,
>  1179.4448046206896,
>  779.212183,
>  515.3126512413794,
>  1567.015775862069,
>  646.5571051034483]
> ```

He excluido `p` del ciclo porque no la usas en el código que muestras, pero si la requieres la idea es la misma, `for vl, vp, vc in zip(l, p, c)`.

> **Nota:** si se usa Python 2 es mejor usar `itertools.izip` y no el built-in `zip`. Este último en Python 2 retorna una lista, no un iterador como hace en Python 3, por lo que creamos una lista temporal en memoria que no es necesaria.